# Factorygirl set has_many as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a `user` factory that be default creates an association for `user_document`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    sequence(:first_name) {|n| "firstname-#{n}" }
    after(:create) do |user|
      create(:user_document, document_type: :address_proof, user: user)
    end
  end
end
```

I'd like to define a new factory for which the association user_document is null. How do I do this ?

[UPDATE]

When I do this

```
  factory :user_with_no_doc_buyer do
    user_document nil
  end
```

I get an error saying :

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `user_document=' for #<User:0x007f97329c08f8>
```

and When I do 
`user_documents nil` I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create two traits.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:first_name) {|n| "firstname-#{n}" }

    trait :with_document do
      after(:create) do |user|
        create(:user_document, document_type: :address_proof, user: user)
      end
    end

    trait :without_document do
      user_documents []
    end
  end
end
```

Then you just call whichever factory you need.

`FactoryGirl.create(:user, :with_document)` for example

Edit: Have seen you want the with document to be the default. That's easy enough. You can just use the code you have and take my suggestion of a trait without document which you can call when you need it.

Comment: Ok thanks for this, but the user_document nil doesn't work for me `undefined method user_document=' for #<User:0x007fa28e1c5010>`  `user has_many :user_documents`

Comment: My apologies. It should be `[]` instead of nil. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [traits](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    sequence(:first_name) {|n| "firstname-#{n}" }
    trait :with_user_document
      after(:create) do |user|
        create(:user_document, document_type: :address_proof, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

To create user with document

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user, :with_user_document)
```

To create user with null document

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

Comment: the thing is that I'd like to make with_user_document my default behavior.

Comment: Idea is to use trait. you can define your trait however you want